# Taking one parameter (class) and returning table of methods of the class parameter

Tags: ruby, reflection

I would like to know how to declare a function that takes one parameter (class) and returns a table of methods of the class parameter. The function needs to use reflection. Any samples would be great.

Comment: Can you please show us a sample input, and what output you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Try `methods` and `instance_methods`.